# rspec error in ruby with before each do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am working through the Learn Rails By Example book and came across an interesting problem. I'll apologize in advance if I am just doing something wrong. Here is the problem.

In section 3.5, the exercise it asks you to do the following:

> You may have noticed some repetition in the Pages controller spec (Listing 3.20). In particular, the base title, “Ruby on Rails Tutorial
>   Sample App”, is the same for every title test. Using the RSpec
>   before(:each) facility, which executes a block of code before each
>   test case, fill in Listing 3.33 to define a @base_title instance
>   variable that eliminates this duplication. (This code uses two new
>   elements: a symbol, :each, and the string concatenation operator +.
>   We’ll learn more about both in Chapter 4, and we’ll see before(:each)
>   again in Section 6.2.1.) Note that, with the base title captured in an
>   instance variable, we are now able to align :content with the first
>   character inside each left parenthesis (. This is my preferred
>   convention for formatting code broken into multiple lines.

Here is how my pages_controller_spec.rb looks:

```
describe PagesController do
  render_views

  before(:each) do
    # Define @base_title here.
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector("title",
                                    :content => @base_title + " | Home")
    end
  end
```

When I load the rails server and open the webpage, everything works perfect. The title shows up as it should per the base_title. However, when I run rspec, I receive the following errors. I'd really like to get this cleared up in rspec. What do you think is wrong?

```
  1) PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: :content => @base_title + " | Home")
     NoMethodError:
       You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
       You might have expected an instance of Array.
       The error occurred while evaluating nil.+
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:20

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:17 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `@base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"` at line 6, not base_title.  A variable defined as you do there does not automatically become an instance variable

Comment: we all have to start somewhere :-)